# Android multiple alarms not working

Tags: android, alarmmanager

```
public static boolean setupAlarm(String flightName, long columnId, int time,int requestCode, Context context) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager;


    FlightTimeObject timeObject = DataCheckingUtils.getConvertedTime(time);

    try {
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), ProcessAlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra(IntentActions.INTENT_REQUEST_CODE, requestCode);
        intent.putExtra(IntentActions.INTENT_SEND_STRING_FLIGHT, flightName);
        intent.putExtra(IntentActions.INTENT_SEND_FLIGHT_COLUMN_ID, columnId);


        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, intent,0);

        //Get calendar instance
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

        //get hour
        if (timeObject.getHour()!= -1) {
            int hour = timeObject.getHour();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        }

        //get minute
        if (timeObject.getMinute()!=-1){
            int minute = timeObject.getMinute();
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        }

        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        assert alarmManager != null;

        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                pendingIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Hello everyone.  The above code gets called within a for loop, underneath.

```
private static void setupAlarmToFlight(ArrayList<FlightObject> flightArray, Context context) {


    int numberOfAlarms = 0;
    int requestCode = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < flightArray.size(); i++){
        FlightObject flight = flightArray.get(i);
        String name = flight.getFlightName();
        long flightColumnId = flight.getColumnId();
        int flightActualTime = flight.getActualArrivalTime();
        int scheduledTime = flight.getFlightScheduledTime();
        int timeToParse =  -2;
        if (flightActualTime == -2){
            timeToParse = scheduledTime;
        }else{
            timeToParse = flightActualTime;
        }
        boolean alarmSet = ExtractFlightUtilities.setupAlarm(
                name,
                flightColumnId,
                timeToParse,
                requestCode,
                context);

        if (alarmSet){
            numberOfAlarms++;
            requestCode++;
        }
    }
        Intent intent = new Intent(IntentActions.ALARM_SET);
        intent.putExtra(IntentActions.INTENT_SEND_INT, numberOfAlarms);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

This code basically sets alarms for different flight arrival times from an arraylist that will start a service. The first alarm always fires right on time, but the rest never fire. I even stopped the service so it would just get to the receiver, but only the first fires. I also stopped the for loop at 2-3 alarms, but nothing.

I made sure that the hours and minutes are set correctly, and used another loop that would just set alarm in one minute after each but no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDITED:**

I tried the suggestion and still not firing the alarms.
Something interesting I noticed, when setting breakpoints, the debugger gives preview values, and the first alarm that goes off okay, it's values, such as the requestCode and the Calendar values are green.  All other following alarms are red.

**For the first alarm**.
The request code is green.
[image]

The pending intent looks all green.
[image]

The calendar value looks all green.
[image]

**For all the other alarms.**

The request code is red.
[image]

The pending intent request code red:
[image]

The calendar value is red
[image]

Again thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you set exact time, it might be because you did not check if the alarm time set is not passed already. E.g. consider the current date/time is `1-Jan-2018 11:30PM`. If you set alarm for `01:00AM`, based on your code, the alarm will be set for `1-Jan-2018 01:00AM` since you used:

```
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis())
```

which returns `1-Jan-2018 11:30PM` and the you set time to `01:00AM` which change the date to `1-Jan-2018 01:00AM` which is passed. In this case you should add to alarm date one day. Something like this:

```
/**
 * adjust time and date of alarm (alarms set in some previous years, will updated to today).
 * if time is passed in today, date will +1
 *
 * @param alarmTimeCalendar time which may need adjustments
 * @return adjusted time for alarm
 */
public static Calendar adjustAlarmTime(Calendar alarmTimeCalendar) {
    Calendar adjustedDateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = alarmTimeCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = alarmTimeCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    adjustedDateCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    adjustedDateCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    adjustedDateCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Date currentDate = adjustedDateCalendar.getTime();
    Date alarmDate = adjustedDateCalendar.getTime();
    long difference = alarmDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime();
    if (difference < 0) {
        adjustedDateCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    return adjustedDateCalendar;
}
```

Comment: Thank you , I will try your suggestion, and get back to you. Thank you again.

Comment: thank you, I passed the calendar through your method, and still the same. I noticed a couple of red values that are not causing any error or crashes on the debugger.  I edited the OP with more information, thank you. @VSB

Answer (score 0):

So after trying multiple ways of approaching the problem, I solved it by setting the alarm as only RTC and not RTC_WAKEUP.  Now all the alarms are firing right on time.

Thank you all.